# how can I get both context and target vectors in Pyspark.ml Word2vec?

Tags: python, pyspark, word2vec, word-embedding

I need to save/access/obtain both context vectors and target vectors when I fit/train my model. More clearly, Word2vec trains two layers' weights also known as context vectors and target vectors. It seems I can only save/access context vectors. Here is my code:

```
from Pyspark.ml.feature import Word2vec, Word2vecModel
wv=Word2vec(settings)
model = wv.fit(doc)
model.getVectors().show()
model.findSynonymsArray("Something", 10)
model.write().overwrite().save(filePath)
myModel = Word2vecModel.load(filePath)
```

model and myModel only contain context vectors. How can I have target vectors (neural networks' output weights)?

Comment: I don't think it is currently possible :/ I switched to GenSim